What is the difference between k-averaged transmission and gamma point transmission?
When I used Transiesta to calculate transmission, I found that k-averaged transmission is the same as gamma point transmission for some devices and they are different for other devices.
What is the difference between k-averaged transmission and gamma point transmission?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Like any periodic structure, one needs to converge results based on a brilluoin zone integration.
For DFT calculations one uses a k-point sampling to correctly describe periodic wavefunctions in the structure.
For transport, the same applies. And this one should always do convergence tests for number of k-points in the transport calculations. And typically, the required k-points for transport calculations are typically much more dense than the density calculations.

Sir, if I understand correctly, you mean if k-averaged transmission is different from gamma point transmission, then this means that the k-points for transport calculations have not converged.

No, that is not what I mean. Generally the gamma-point transport is different from the k-averaged transmission. One should converge the number of k-points in the k-averaged transmission, just like any other physical quantity.

Thank you, Sir!

The transmission we got after transport calculations is a function of k-point and energy, that is, a transmission spectrum[1]. We can extract the function of the transmission at any k-point in Brillouin Zone with respect to energy.
The transmission at the gamma point is not necessarily equal to the k-averaged transmission[2].
K-averaged transmission provides a more comprehensive and accurate description of transport by sampling multiple k-points in the BZ.
Gamma point transmission focuses on how the electronic states near the Gamma point affect the transport properties.
[1] Beilstein J. Nanotechnol. 2015, 6, 1603–1608.doi:10.3762/bjnano.6.164
[2] doi:10.1103/PhysRevB.88.161401

Thank you, Sir, I have modified my answer.
